# CSS: Half of screen image and half of screen background-color with a container over it

Tags: css

I'm ussing Bootstrap 4 and wanna try to make a layout like in the screenshot with a normal container of bootstrap over it so my text is nicely alind in te right 6 columns.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfRQj.png)

Comment: have a look at the push and pull classes

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Simply adjust the `background-size` of your background image:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
 background:
  url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) left/50% 100% no-repeat,
  orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `linear-gradient`

```css
body{
background-image:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, orange 50%), url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg');

}
```